# Make JFrame modal or show JDialog on taskbar

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jdialog

I have a `JFrame` that sometimes I need it to act as a frame with it's own task-bar icon, but also I need to use it as a `JDialog` without task-bar icon and modal of a parent frame.

Is that possible? I don't know how to implement it, so I can't put any code.

Comment: *"Is that possible?"*  Sure.  Design the GUI in a `JPanel`, then show the panel in a modal dialog or frame as required.  But I really have to wonder what use-case calls for either showing it in a frame, or the choice between the two modes.  See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556)

Comment: @AndrewThompson so for this I am asking, this. The frame is a selector with buttons and I need to act is as a JFrame when the application starts and as a dialog when it works a as a selector with toggle buttons and I don't want to repeat code with a JDialog and a JFrame

Comment: *"The frame is a selector with buttons and I need to act is as a JFrame when the application starts and as a dialog when it works a as a selector with toggle buttons."*  Hmm.. 'what' but not a 'why'..  I'm more interested in the 'why'.

Comment: What do you mean with why?

Comment: .. I don't get it - are you saying you don't understand what '[why](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/why)?' means?  See also [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)

Comment: No I know the meaning of why, I will explain better, The frame is the main window when the user opens the application. In that context I want it working as a JFrame, with it's icon on task-bar. But I have other frame that opens this and I want to open it as JDialog, with the modality of a parent window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it by making the main component a JPanel and then embedding it in a JFrame or in a JDialog.

Thanks for the idea Andrew Thompson